# Do I need to go through customs, immigration and security for a connection in Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, sin

I have flights from Manila to Singapore and from Singapore to Bangkok, both on a different airline and ticket. Both flights will be in Terminal 1 and have a 5-hour gap in between. Do I still need to go through and exit immigration (for Manila/Singapore and enter again (for Singapore-Bangkok)?

Comment: Will you have any checked luggage?

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: Depends a bit on the check in procedure of the 2nd airline. Check in desks and kiosks are outside of  immigration. If you can check in online, you are good. Some airlines have customer service desk or kiosks airside, so you can check in there. Some may allow you to check in with the gate agent.  If you need to physically show up at a check in counter, you will have to go through immigration.

Answer (score 2):

Singapore has sterile transit available in all terminals, so if your bags are checked through or you have hand luggage only, **you will not go through Customs or Immigration.**

However, you *may* go through security on arrival at the gate, and you *will* go through security at your departure gate.  Singapore laws apply if you're caught with any contraband, up to and including [the death penalty for drug trafficking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Tuong_Nguyen).

Comment: I only have a hand luggage.
So, if I understand it correctly, I don't have to go to the immigration (fr MNL-SIN flight) to have an exit; and I can just proceed to my next flight?

Comment: You seem to have created a duplicate account. If you log into the account with which you posted this question, you'll be able to comment on jpatokal's answer. But the answer to your question is yes, you don't need to go through immigration.

Comment: Didn't know there were situations where you have to go through security on arrival. Is that a fact (I suppose only for flights from some specific destinations?), or just a supposition? Given the fact you don't go through security when entering the transit/departures area from outside, this would be quite weird. Not to mention the hassle of processing a planeload of people at the quite small security checkpoints at the gates (at a rate which is in theory higher than upon departure).

Comment: @jcaron It's a fact alright, I lived in Singapore for years and used Changi weekly.  They profile, flights from Indonesia in particular tended to get scrutiny -- not every flight, but maybe 1 in 5?  Yes, the check is at the gate when disembarking, and yes, it can be a bit of a pain, although it usually only adds a few mins.  At Changi all security is at the gate, so they're quite efficient at it.